# Inno Setup Compiler: How to edit INI file and replace a value with {app} constant

Tags: inno-setup

I have a INI file which contains `c:/wamp` many times.

How can I replace this text with the `{app}` extended/chosen constant value?

I know now how to replace a single value:

```
[INI]
Filename: "{app}\wampmanager.conf"; Section: "main"; Key: "installDir"; String: """{app}"""
```

I am reading from [here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall)

Comment: You can use `LoadStringFromFile` and then `StringChange` where you will replace `c:/wamp` (any string) with `{app}`. Just keep in mind that if INI is ANSI and you use Unicode IS, then you have to point it in the script.

Comment: @RobeN, I strongly suggest to not do this! That file is obviously generated by a certain external installer and by this blind replace you can modify keys that you don't want to change. I urge you to make a list of all those keys.

Comment: the file is big, so a list is out of the question; i need a find and replace method

Comment: No, you don't need it. You want it.

Comment: so, how do i replace all the values without that list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is risky solution as TLama says.

You have to call this procedure at some point, e.g. on `ssDone` or as an `AfterInstall`

```
[Code]
procedure Update;
var
A: AnsiString;
U: String;
begin
    LoadStringFromFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\wampmanager.conf'), A);
    U := A;
    StringChange(U, 'c:/wamp', ExpandConstant('{app}'));
    A := U;
    SaveStringToFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\wampmanager.conf'), A, False);
end;
```

Comment: This is very risky. Better list all strings you have to replace. E.g. in Excel you may filter that out and then create script for INI section.

Comment: ok, so, now, i must somehow wait until my app finishes to edit this file also;\

Comment: is this waiting code ok? if(WaitForSingleObject(ExecInfo.hProcess, Timeout) = WAIT_OBJECT_0) then
  Result := Boolean(ShellExecuteEx(ExecInfo));

Comment: You need to know what you are waiting for. Now you're going to wait for the process specified by the `ExecInfo.hProcess` to terminate. But it looks a bit suspicious. Are you sure that member constains a valid process handle (since that subsequent call of `ShellExecuteEx` looks strange) ? Anyway, please use `@` char before the user's name for comment notifications and please try to work on a single problem per question. Thanks!